# Running Babel across a monorepo of packages/components

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, package.json

I'm trying to build a React component library, but each component will have its own unique dependencies. To keep it tidy, I've started a monorepo using Yarn's Workspaces. It currently looks like this:

```
components
    component1
        src
            index.js
        dist ???
        package.json
    component2
        src
            index.js
        dist ???
        package.json
node_modules
package.json
.babelrc
etc.
```

I'd like to be able to run a Babel command at the root level that compiles each `src/index.js` to its relative `dist/index.js`. Is this possible? Or can anyone recommend a tool that can iterate this?

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out. Install Lerna at root-level (with Workspace flag, to allow it to install).

```
yarn add --dev lerna -W
```

Initialise lerna.

```
node_modules/lerna/bin/lerna.js init
```

Update `lerna.json` to point to the "components" directory.

```
{
  "lerna": "2.5.1",
  "packages": ["components/*"],
  "version": "0.0.0"
}
```

Add script to root-level `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "build-components": "NODE_ENV=production lerna exec --parallel -- babel src -d dist",
  ...
},
```

Comment: How do you manage babel to pick the correct babelrc at the root of the repo ?

Comment: @Danielo515 to be honest, I don't remember asking this question, let alone answering it! I think it was something I was experimenting with in my last job. The fact I don't remember this shows we didn't go on to use it. The `/.babelrc` is used by default: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babelrc#lookup-behavior

Comment: this is not enough, how one compiled folder will get another?